# Shadowbox container is undefined error

Tags: javascript, shadowbox

I'm trying to open Shadowbox on page load, i've tried different code i found here and on the web but cant get it to work.  Keep getting a container is undefined error...

Heres my code

```
<link href="js/shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        Shadowbox.init({
            language:   "en",
       players:    ["img"]
        });

        $('document').ready(function() {
                Shadowbox.open({
                        content: "images/popup_sd.png",
                        player:     "img",
                        title:      "Welcome",
                        height:     403,
                        width:      744
                });    
        });
</script>
```

Simple enough...  can anyone tell me whats going on please, would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using?  Have you tried this with jQuery 1.4.2 instead of 1.4.3?

Comment: yep tried with both versions of jquery.  whats weird is when i use window.onload = function() {...  it works???